# REGEX for first and last names involving dots (.)

Tags: c++, regex, match

I want to be able to get the first and last name always starting with a capital letter... This I've already achieved in a post here on stackoverflow, it's this one:

`[A-Z][a-z]+([ ][A-Z][a-z]+)*`

However, according to my business rules, I need to be able to validate names and surnames with only the first letter of the first and last name followed by a period and space, or only by a period if the period is at the end of the string.

For example:

```
"John Doe" -> true
"John D." -> true
"John D. D." -> true
"John D. D. " -> false (as here we have a space after the last dot in S.)
"John D.  D." -> false (as here two spaces after the first . in B.)
"John D.oe" -> false (as here we have a point not being followed by a space)
```

In order to get around this situation, I wrote the following code that simply means a dot ( `.`) followed by a space ( ), however I don't know what else to do and I don't know how to introduce this code there in the REGEX specified above...

([.][\s]?)

The regex I came up with is incomplete and does not produce the result I am seeking for:

`^[A-Z](?:[a-z]|[\.])+(?:[ ][A-Z](?:[a-z]|[\.])+)*$`

`John D.oe` -> matches true, however it should not as there is supposed to have a space after every dot...

Does someone out there know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?:[a-z]|[\.])+` is equivalent to `[a-z.]+` (no need for dot to be escaped here)

You want `[A-Z](?:[a-z]+|\.)` (not sure if `+` should be `*`, can name have only one letter (without abbreviation)).

Result would be:

`^[A-Z](?:\.|[a-z]*)(?: [A-Z](?:\.|[a-z]*))+$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z7Q3FE/1)

```
"John Doe"      // true
"John D."       // true
"John D. D."    // true
"John D. D. "
"John D.  D."
"John D.oe"
"J. Doe"        // true
"J. D."         // true
"John DDoe"
```

Comment: We are almost there @Jarod42... Your code fails only at `John` a single name

Comment: You didn't specify user can not have name (as ["Juste LeBlanc"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5_ruQ8okms) (from French movie)). Replace last `+` by `*` then.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to match the regular expression

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z](?:[a-z]+|\.(?: [A-Z]\.)?)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2rXek/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^              # match beginning of string
[A-Z]          # match an uppercase letter
[a-z]+         # match one or more lowercase letters
[ ][A-Z]       # match a space followed by an uppercase letter
(?:            # begin a non-capture group
  [a-z]+       # match one or more lowercase letters
|              # or
  \.           # match a period
  (?:          # begin a non-capture group
    [ ][A-Z]\. # match a space followed by an uppercase letter
               # followed by a period   
  )?           # end inner non-capture group and make it optional
)              # end outer non-capture group
$              # match the end of the string
```

I have enclosed spaces in character classes (`[ ]`) above merely to make them visible.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, Cary Swoveland ... However your solution still does fail in some results as for instance John D. Doe, John D. D. Doe and John Doe Doe

Comment: I will revise my answer but I would ask you to first edit your question to clarify your requirements. In particular, please add  enough additional examples to make clear which strings are valid and which are not. None of your current examples are remotely like the strings in your comment above.